# Adding partials and multiple results to this JS search Function

Tags: javascript

Currently the function displays only 1 correct result from an array based on 2 variables.

**Array Sample Data**

```
[{"username": "lromero2l", "first_name": "Lawrence", "last_name": "Romero", "gender": "Male", "sexuality": "Public-key value-added array", "bestFriend": "loperamide HCl"}, {"username": "glopez2o", "first_name": "Gloria", "last_name": "Lopez", "gender": "Female", "sexuality": "Balanced multi-tasking time-frame", "bestFriend": "Aconite, Arnica, Calendula, Hypericum, Ledum, Ruta Grav."}, {"username": "ereyes2p", "first_name": "Elizabeth", "last_name": "Reyes", "gender": "Female", "sexuality": "Future-proofed systemic infrastructure", "bestFriend": "Tretinoin"}, {"username": "ppalmer2q", "gender": "Male", "sexuality": "Optimized multi-tasking circuit", "bestFriend": "Pantoprazole Sodium"}, {"username": "harmstrong2r", "first_name": "Helen", "last_name": "Armstrong", "gender": "Female", "sexuality": "Seamless zero tolerance interface", "bestFriend": "ERYTHROMYCIN"}]
```

**Search Function**

```
function myFunction(e) {
    if((e.target.id === 'mySearch' && e.keyCode === 13) || e.target.id === 'searchButton'){
        e.preventDefault();
        var searchValue = document.getElementById("mySearch").value;
        for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
        if(users[i]['bestFriend'] === searchValue || (users[i]['username'] === searchValue)){
        document.getElementById("usernameOut").innerHTML = ("USERNAME" + '<br/>' + users[i].username);
        document.getElementById("firstNameOut").innerHTML = ("FIRST NAME" + '<br/>' + users[i].first_name);
        document.getElementById("lastNameOut").innerHTML = ("LAST NAME" + '<br/>' + users[i].last_name);
        document.getElementById("genderOut").innerHTML = ("GENDER" + '<br/>' + users[i].gender);
        document.getElementById("sexualityOut").innerHTML = ("SEXUALITY" + '<br/>' + users[i].sexuality);
        document.getElementById("friendOut").innerHTML = ("BEST FRIEND" + '<br/>' + users[i].bestFriend);
        displayImage();
        document.getElementById("main_text").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("return").style.display = "block";
        return;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like the Function to display partial results. I.e. if 4+ of the characters are correct, then display the whole result.

I also need the function to display multiple results. (I.e. if the term is similar to either 'bestFriend' or 'username' values, display.)  Would this mean restructuring 'ID' to 'Class'? I have tried fiddling with `if(users[i]['bestFriend'] === searchValue || (users[i]['username'] === searchValue))` to allow more leeway with searched terms, but everything seems to break the function. What part of the function would need to change/what would i need to add to achieve this?

Please don't hesitate to ask for this to be edited. I'm pretty knackered and still kinda new to SO. Thanks!

Comment: The only question I'm seeing here is *"Would this mean restructuring 'ID' to 'Class'?"* - It would certainly be a better idea then trying to maintain a bunch of unique IDs, but you don't *have* to.

Comment: @Santi Thanks. I've changed the request slightly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is short example on how use can utilize Levenshtein distance to achieve this.

> Levenshtein distance (LD) is a measure of the similarity between two strings, which we will refer to as the source string (s) and the target string (t). The distance is the number of deletions, insertions, or substitutions required to transform s into t.

Distance function taken from here: https://gist.github.com/andrei-m/982927

*Edit: reading again your question made me realize this is not exactly what you asked for and a simple substr match would have sufficed here*

```js
/*
Copyright (c) 2011 Andrei Mackenzie
Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
*/

// Compute the edit distance between the two given strings
function distance(a, b) {
  if (a.length == 0) return b.length;
  if (b.length == 0) return a.length;

  var matrix = [];

  // increment along the first column of each row
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i <= b.length; i++) {
    matrix[i] = [i];
  }

  // increment each column in the first row
  var j;
  for (j = 0; j <= a.length; j++) {
    matrix[0][j] = j;
  }

  // Fill in the rest of the matrix
  for (i = 1; i <= b.length; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= a.length; j++) {
      if (b.charAt(i - 1) == a.charAt(j - 1)) {
        matrix[i][j] = matrix[i - 1][j - 1];
      } else {
        matrix[i][j] = Math.min(matrix[i - 1][j - 1] + 1, // substitution
          Math.min(matrix[i][j - 1] + 1, // insertion
            matrix[i - 1][j] + 1)); // deletion
      }
    }
  }

  return matrix[b.length][a.length];
};



const users = [{
  "username": "lromero2l",
  "first_name": "Lawrence",
  "last_name": "Romero",
  "gender": "Male",
  "sexuality": "Public-key value-added array",
  "bestFriend": "loperamide HCl"
}, {
  "username": "glopez2o",
  "first_name": "Gloria",
  "last_name": "Lopez",
  "gender": "Female",
  "sexuality": "Balanced multi-tasking time-frame",
  "bestFriend": "Aconite, Arnica, Calendula, Hypericum, Ledum, Ruta Grav."
}, {
  "username": "ereyes2p",
  "first_name": "Elizabeth",
  "last_name": "Reyes",
  "gender": "Female",
  "sexuality": "Future-proofed systemic infrastructure",
  "bestFriend": "Tretinoin"
}, {
  "username": "ppalmer2q",
  "gender": "Male",
  "sexuality": "Optimized multi-tasking circuit",
  "bestFriend": "Pantoprazole Sodium"
}, {
  "username": "harmstrong2r",
  "first_name": "Helen",
  "last_name": "Armstrong",
  "gender": "Female",
  "sexuality": "Seamless zero tolerance interface",
  "bestFriend": "ERYTHROMYCIN"
}];

const max_distance = 3

const renderValue = ([key, val]) => `<div><span>${key}:</span><span> ${val}</span></div>`

const renderUser = (user) => `<div class="user">${Object.entries(user).map(renderValue).join('')}</div>`

const checkValue = (term, value) => distance(term, value) <= max_distance

const search = (term) => users.filter(item => 
  Object.values(item)
    .filter(value => checkValue(term, value)).length > 0) // searches all object values for a match

const render = (term) => {
  const html = search(term)
    .map(renderUser)
    .join('')

  document.querySelector('.users').innerHTML = html;
}

document.querySelector('.query')
  .addEventListener('input', (e) => render(e.target.value))
```

```css
div {
  display: block
}

.user {
  padding: 5px
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="query" placeholder="search me"/>
<div class='users'></div>
```